# limit os.walk to a certain number of files

Tags: python

I want to index, say 150 files, so that the `os.walk` terminates after only going through 150 files.

**for example:**
say the first folder to be indexed has 20 files, the second 30, 4th 10, 5th 120, 6th 22, the *'walk'* should aggregate the total number from all folders as it goes through each until the sum reaches 150, then terminate.

This doesn't work:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

i = 0
while i <= 150:
    print(i)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/'):
        i += 1
        for f in files:
            print(f, 'ROOT: ', root, 'DIR: ', dirs)
```

Please help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 0
j=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/'):
        i += 1 
        if i > 150: #this is 150 folders (not files)
           break
        for f in files:
            j+= 1
            if j > 150:  #this is 150 files
               i=151 # force exit the outer loop
               break
            print(f, 'ROOT: ', root, 'DIR: ', dirs)
```

Comment: `i > 150` does *not* mean 150 folders deep, just that you scanned 150 folders.

Comment: Hey @Joran Beasley. Thank you so much for the answer. Could you know how I could get the file size of each file during each iteration?

Comment: `os.path.getsize(filepath)`

Comment: Why the separate count for folders *at all*? What if these 150 files are evenly spread across 100s of folders? Your code will bail out early, yet the OP has not stated any such a requirement.

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate a flaw in his logic ... i doubted that was what he intended but he had i incrementing and was trying to use it to bail out... I agree I dont think he wants the folder count, but I was just trying to show the logic error

Comment: Why not *make that explicit* in your answer then?

Answer (score 3):

You need to test your file number **inside** the `os.walk()` loop:

```
i = 150
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/'):
    if i <= 0:
        break

    for f in files[:i]:
        i -= 1
        print(f, 'ROOT: ', root, 'DIR: ', dirs)
```

I used slicing of `files` to simplify the test here as `break` will only end the inner-most active loop. By counting down, the slice operation is simplified a little.

Over-slicing `files` is perfectly legal; if there are only 20 items slicing to 150 returns just the 20 items available. In the meantime `i` is decreased by 20, so the next folder lets you process at most 130 files, etc.